# SAS: "ERROR: Rename of temporary member for WORK.XXXX.DATA failed"

Tags: error-handling, sas

I'm having a problem in SAS and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem or found a solution.

The problem occurs when I am sorting a dataset that I have created in a previous DATA step. I am using the temporary WORK directory but the problem also occurs with a permanent directory. The sort will sometimes succeed but will sometimes fail with a message like:

ERROR: Rename of temporary member for WORK.xxxx.DATA failed.
 File may be found in C:\Users\BLAHBLAHBLAH.

The SAS technicians have been of no help, and Google searches have been fruitless - lots of confused questioners and no clear solutions. The problem is not related to UAC or permissions or memory or disk space.

The problem occurs on multiple PCs with different specs, including some with ample computing resources to spare; we haven't tried it outside of a Win7 environment but the issue seems to be with SAS itself or an interaction between SAS and either Win7 or McAfee. It's not the size of the dataset; the problematic dataset has roughly a million cells and we can't replicate the problem with larger datasets. And the script we're using worked perfectly fine last year.

Has anyone out there encountered this problem? If so, have you found a solution? If not, what have you tried? Thank you!

James

Comment: I'd blame McAfee.  Turn it off entirely, see if the problem goes away.

Comment: If only we could! This is a work problem on work computers though, and the IT department has made it clear they're not going to budge over this. If the computer is turned on McAfee will be running. Can't even test it to see if turning McAfee off produces different results. SMH but that's what happens when IT policy is dictated by occasional bouts of executive panic. As an extra bonus, there's PII involved so I can't take the data elsewhere. Either I figure this out on a work computer or not at all. Great fun.

Comment: See if IT will tell McAfee not to scan a particular folder.  This isn't a problem that's really wide scale, hence the lack of google finds, so it's probably something specific to your setup.

Comment: Right on. I'll pester them about it and if they try it I'll post the results here. Thanks Joe!

Comment: Sadly it didn't work; next I'll be trying Rob's approach as described below.

Answer (score 1):

Joe is probably right.  Most likely a sharing violation caused by AV software.  Because this is happening in your work folder it's unlikely that it's being caused by anything other than AV.

You can prove that it's the AV causing the sharing violation by using process monitor.  There's a pretty good guide on how to do it here:

[How to debug "Sharing Violation" when trying to delete a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450860/how-to-debug-sharing-violation-when-trying-to-delete-a-file)

Good luck.

Comment: Great, thank you Rob. Telling McAfee not to scan the temp folder didn't work, so I'm talking to IT about using procmon as described in your link. I'll post the results when I'm done.

Comment: Feel free not to mark it as correct until you have some success. As much as I'd like the points I'd rather know whether it successfully resolves it or not ;-)